# Update data in .xls or .xlsx file

Tags: java, xls

I have key value based record of list which one is huge, I used **'CellReference'**, I just want know any other way is possible in efficient way, because I thing that **'CellReference'** get more time to update.

Data have like this way:-

```
      Column/value

       B9     35
       B8     63
       B7     11
       B6     36
       B5     87
       B14    3066
       B13    5025
```

And My code for Iteration each pair is :-

```
        Map<String,Integer> result= getMap();//getting Column and value
        Iterator it = result.entrySet().iterator();
        CellReference reference=null;
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) it.next();
                reference = new CellReference(pair.getKey().toString());
                Row row = spreadsheet.getRow(reference.getRow());
                Cell cell = null;
                if (row != null) {
                    cell = row.getCell(ref.getCol());
                }
            if (cell != null)
                cell.setCellValue(Double.parseDouble(pair.getValue().toString()));
        }
```

Comment: in which prospectives you are looking for -> other way is possible in efficient way.if it is working.

Comment: I want any efficient way ?

Answer (score 0):

The term efficient is quite unclear here , but you could also try as

```
          List<String> dataList = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<Integer> rowNo=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> colNo=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int countRow=1;
    int countCol=1;
    try {

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    //  System.out.println("loadinggg !!!");
        HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
        HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();

        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
            rowNo.add(countRow);
            Row row = rowIterator.next();
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                cell = cellIterator.next();
                switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING: {
                    dataList.add(cell.getStringCellValue());
                    cell.setCellValue("iterate through your own list here");
                }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: There is also requirement of readable smooth code prior to efficient in some sence.

Comment: Thanks, but in this manner it will be iterate all column if I try to insert value Nth column.

Comment: You could use position as a parameter , or iterate through position collection and use it instead !